# How to display a dataframe with aggregated rows and string values?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I want to transform an dataframe with parent customers name with child servers into a "nested" table with just one parent customer and its childs servers. I don't know what is the best way to achieve this in pandas if using groupby or a pivot table.

I have a dataset like below:

```
Customer  ID    Server      TYPE  OS
John    100   prod1  PROD         Linux
John    100   prod2  PROD         Linux            
John    100   prod3  PROD         Linux
Smith    101   prod1  PROD         Linux
Smith    101   prod2  PROD         Linux
Smith    101   prod3  PROD         Linux
Smith    101   prod4  PROD         Linux
```

How can I best represent my data to show this parent child structure for each customer? Ideally, I would like to classify this set above as a two customers like below:

```
Customer  ID    Server      TYPE  OS
John    100   prod1  PROD         Linux
              prod2  PROD         Linux            
              prod3  PROD         Linux
Smith   101   prod1  PROD         Linux
              prod2  PROD         Linux
              prod3  PROD         Linux
              prod4  PROD         Linux
```

Preferrably, I want the childs on a row below the parent like below:

```
Customer  ID    Server      TYPE  OS
John    100   
              prod1  PROD         Linux
              prod2  PROD         Linux            
              prod3  PROD         Linux
Smith   101   
              prod1  PROD         Linux
              prod2  PROD         Linux
              prod3  PROD         Linux
              prod4  PROD         Linux
```

I expect to have a new dataframe with the data in a parent child relationship.

Comment: If you want to just display, then `df.set_index(['Customer', 'ID'])` would do.

Comment: I think display wasn't actually the correct word for it. I want a new dataframe with the parent-child relationship.

Comment: That also gives sort of parent-child relationship. after `df.set_index(['Customer', 'ID'], inplace=True)` you can do, e.g., df[('John', 100)]` and get all the information about the pair.

Comment: that didn't work for me

Comment: I mean `df.loc[('John', 100)]` or maybe `df.loc[('John', '100')]` if `100` is text.

Comment: I meant that ```df.set_index(['Customer', 'ID'])``` didn't work for me. It didn't gave me a parent-child relationship dataframe.